# C++ template argument type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Given a templated function declared like this:

```
template<class T>
int Function(T object);
```

A user can invoke this function by specifying the templated type, like this:

```
int result = Function<float>(100.f); // Valid
```

But the type specification is optional, as the compiler can deduce the type of T from the supplied argument's type; like this:

```
int result = Function(100.f); // Also valid, the compiler deduced the type "float" from the literal's type
```

Let's say I get a little more complicated, and I want a templated value parameter like this:

```
template<class T, T* object>
int Function();
```

I can call my function in this way:

```
static float val = 100.f;
// ...
int result = Function<float, &val>();
```

My question is: **is there any way I coerce the compiler to deduce the type T based on the type of the argument &val?**

What I need is a way to make the following code valid:

```
static float val = 100.f;
// ...
int result = Function<&val>();
```

Can it be done?

Comment: It should be possible in C++17.

Comment: Function<decltype(&val)>() but that's not really deduction.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve would help a lot.

Comment: Template parameter cannot be a pointer. It can only be a type or primitive type

Comment: @Jarod42, I knew they were improving template parameter deduction in C++17, but not that they had that. Would that just be `template<auto* object> int Function();` (perhaps with `using T=decltype(object)` inside), or is something more complicated?

Comment: @balki and template parameters must be constant expression

Comment: Template parameters can be pointers or references to something with static storage duration (see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_non-type_arguments)

Comment: Daniel is correct. See https://ideone.com/WBQSVu The key thing is that the pointer has to have a static address, it can't be a local or dynamically allocated variable.

Comment: @balki yes they can be pointer and reference to object. As long as the object has static storage duration. Pointer to function can be passed around in template parameter too.

Comment: @DominicDosSantos: I'm not sure what you mean. How can there be any type deduction for `T* object` when you don't use it anywhere (or at least, the compiler doesn't see you using it when you declare and when you call the function)?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you just want to be able to do this for the sake of brevity/elegance, or is there another reason?

Comment: @einpoklum: I believe the compiler should be able to deduce the type at the call site, based on the type of the supplied template parameter.

Comment: @SamMarinelli: Good question. It's a brevity thing. I'm designing an API, and in practice, forcing users to redundantly specify the type of an argument they're already supplying both hurts readability and introduces another source of errors--and with C++ templates, errors can often exceptionally costly for users to resolve.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In C++17, you can have `auto` non-type template parameters.  This will let you solve your problem.

Something *like*:

```
template<auto object, class T=std::decay_t<decltype(*object)>>
int Function();
```

(assuming you want the type `T` within the body of `Function`)

In C++14, the C++17 feature is missing.  It was added exactly because it was missing.  Workarounds involve macros like `#define UGLY_HACK(...) decltype(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__`.

Answer (score 19):

**Note: The answer here has been borrowed from effective modern C++ with a (very) few additions of my own**

This is one of those questions that are easy to pose but difficult to answer! I remember reading an entire ch. apter on template type deduction, and to a rookie reader, the answer is not clear in one read either. Nevertheless, I will try to clarify it here.

One should note that there is something called ***Universal References***  (which are not the same as references or r-value references) that influences template type deduction, and I assume readers know about l-value and r-value references.

Any ubiquitous function template  definition looks like the following:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(paramType param);
```

A call to function would look somehow look like this :

```
function(expression);
```

The compiler uses **expression** to determine the type of **T** and the type of **paramType**. This is so because more often **paramType** contains decorations like **const**, **const&**, **const&&**, etc. Beginners would be tempted to believe that the type **T** deduced by the compiler will be the same as the type of **expression**, i.e., the argument passed to the function, but it is not always the case. Deduction of type **T** depends both on **expression** and **paramType** . Depending on what the function parameter **paramType** is there are three cases to be considered for template type deduction:

1. **paramType** is pointer or reference but not a universal reference.
2. **paramType** is a universal reference.
3. **paramType** is neither a pointer nor a reference.

Let's take a look at each case one by one

### Case 1: paramType is a pointer or a reference but not a universal reference

Call me crazy, but this is the simplest case that can be encountered. In this case, type deduction works like this:
(i) If ***expression*** is a reference, then ignore the reference part
(ii) then match ***expression's*** pattern against ***paramType*** to determine ***T***

Lets take a look at an example :

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(T &param);
```

We have the following variable declarations:

```
int x = 23;               // x is int
const int const_x = x;    // const_x is const int
const int& ref_x = x;     // ref_x is a reference to x as const int
```

The deduced call for ***T*** and ***param*** in various calls are as follows :

```
f(x);                    //T is int, param's type is int&
f(const_x);              //T is const int, param's type is const int&
f(ref_x);                //T is const int, param's type is const int&
```

There are two points to be noted here:

(i) the compiler ignores the reference-ness for type deduction here

(ii) the const-ness becomes a part of type ***T*** when passing a const object or reference to a const object, and hence passing const objects or references to const object to functions taking parameter ***T&*** is safe.

If we change the function parameter from ***T&*** to ***const T&***, because in this case we are assuming ***param*** to be reference to *const*, the ***const***-ness need not be deduced as a part of ***T*** . Below is an example:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(const T& param);  // param is now a ref-to-const

int x = 23;                    // same as previous
const int const_x = x;         // same as previous
const int& ref_x = x;          // same as previous

f(x);                         // T is int, paramType is const int&
f(const_x);                   // T is int, paramType is const int&
f(ref_x);                     // T is int, paramType is const int&
```

**Note**: variable 'x' is not a const argument to 'f()' but it is till deduced as a const param

If ***paramType*** is a pointer, things will work fundamentally the same way as with references. There will be pointers instead of references. E.g., below for the sake of completeness is provided:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function( T* paramType);  // paramType is now a pointer

int x = 23;                      // same as before
const int *pointer_x = &x;       // pointer_x is pointer to x as const int

f(&x);                          // T is int, paramType is int*
f(pointer_x);                   // T is const int, paramType is const int*
```

For the sake of completeness I may as well post the case if **paramType** were a pointer to a constant object like the following:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(const T* paramType);

int x = 23;                      // same as before
const int *pointer_x = &x;       // pointer_x is pointer to x as const int

f(&x);                          // T is int, paramType is const int*
f(pointer_x);                  // T is int, paramType is const int*
```

i.e., again the ***const***-ness is not anymore deduced as a part of T

In case of r-value references, type ***T*** and ***paramType*** deduction follow essentially the same rules as they do in case of l-value references.

This covers most of it for the first case. Let's look at our case 2.

### Case 2: paramType is a universal reference

Universal references are declared like r-value references but take l-value, but what makes their behavior different is that the function arguments receive l-value references. Here's how the type deduction works for this case:

(i) If ***expression*** is an l-value, both ***T*** and ***paramType*** are deduced to be l-value. (This seems strange in the face of how the code looks like because although ***paramType*** is declared using the syntax of r-value reference, its deduced type is of l-value reference.) It should be noted that this is the only case where ***T*** is deduced to be a reference.

The example below clarifies my explanation:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(T&& paramType);  // param becomes universal reference if
                                     // argument to function call is an l-value

int x = 23                     // same as previous
const int const_x = x;         // same as previous
const int& ref_x = x;          // same as previous

f(x);             // x is l-value therefore T is int&
                  // paramType is int&

f(const_x);       // const_x is l-value therefore T is const int&
                  //paramType is also const int&

f(ref_x);        // ref_x is l-value therefore T is const int&
                 // paramType is also const int&

f(23);          // 23 is r-value so T is int
                // paramType is now int&&
```

I want to be honest here and say that this doesn't explain why universal references work the way they do, but I think this post will become too lengthy if I go on to justify it here.

### Case 3: paramType is neither a pointer nor a reference

This is where pass-by-value in template occurs, which implies that param will be a copy of whatever is passed to the argument of the calling function, i.e., a completely new object, and this motivates the rules that govern type deduction of ***T*** from ***expression*** . Two points to be noted here are:

(i) ignore the *refrence*-ness in ***expression*** , if there happens to be one.

(ii) after ignoring the *ref*-ness, ignore *const*-ness or *volatile*-ness too, i.e if present

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(T paramType);

int x = 23;
const int const_x = x;
const int& ref_x = x;

f(x);             // T and paramType are both int
f(const_x);       // T and paramType are both int here too
f(ref_x);         // T and paramType are both int again
```

Note even though const_x and ref_x are const objects which cannot be modified, it doesn't mean that their copies cannot be modified.
This looks straightforward, but it gets tricker when we pass a constant pointer to a constant object. Let's take a look at another example:

```
template <typename T>
returnType function(T param);

const double *const dPtr = 23;  // dPtr is const pointer to const double

function(dPtr);             // passing argument of type const double *const
```

When *const* pointer is passed by value, the *const*-ness is lost, and the pointer is copied by value, which is in sync with the type deduction rules for pass by value, but the *const*-ness of what pointer points to is preserved, and hence the ***paramType*** will be const *double.

This might get your head spinning as it did to me when I started to learn about it. The best way would be to re-read it and try to code it.

Comment: That's almost the contents in effective modern c++.

Comment: i must admit it is!

Comment: @gajendra, **some_expression** should actually be **expression**.

Comment: The chapter is great, but I fail to see how it answers the question. These are the basics of template type deduction formatted in a nice way, but how is that an answer to "*is there any way I coerce the compiler to deduce the type T based on the type of the argument &val?*"?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question

Comment: In `f(&pointer_x); // T is const int, paramType is const int*` isn't `&pointer_x` a pointer-to-pointer type?

Answer (score 0):

For C++-14 I found a possible solution below that, according to my initial test cases, seems to work.

```
class Yada
   {
   template <class Type>
   static IdType getTypeId(Type &fDummy)
      {

      // Use the template parameter alone and ignore fDummy
      return(TypeId<Type>::cTypeId);
      }
   };
```

It's kind of similar approach to CRTP in that the caller has to provide itself as parameter as well:

```
Yada myYadaObject;
myYadaObject.getTypeId(myYadaObject);
```