# How does the pattern matching work for template argument deduction in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am a bit lost in reading the [template argument deduction for function](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.call) specification.

I am searching for some insight in how the pattern matching works.
For example:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T& t);
//       **--------P (T&)

const int& a = ...;
foo(a);
//  *----- A (const int&)
```

As the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125179/c-template-argument-type-deduction) points out:

(i) If `A` is a reference, then ignore the reference part 
(ii) then pattern-match `A` against `P` to determine `T`.

But how is it done and does it work. 
I refere to this [section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Deduction_from_a_type):

> If **P** has one of the forms that include a template parameter list **<T>** or **<I>**, then each element **Pi** of that template argument list is matched against the corresponding template argument **Ai** of its **A**. If the last **Pi** is a pack expansion, then its pattern is compared against each remaining argument in the template argument list of **A**.

which is totally unclear to me...

Comment: `foo(3);
//  *----- ExpressionType (int&&)` is not correct.  In `foo(3)` T gets deduced as an `int` and it fails to compile since you have a non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue.

Comment: Here is a very good reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: Correct ;). But thats not the point: It fails after pattern matching I think. ExpressionType is hopefully correct above

Comment: The expression type is `int`, not `int&&`

Comment: What do you mean by "pattern matching"? 1. Template argument deduction produces `void foo(int&);` 2. Overload resolution fails to find a viable candidate for a call `foo(3);`.

Comment: @ NathanOliver: you are correct

Comment: I think the whole thing is written here: [https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/temp.deduct.type]