# a question about the "getlline" function in c++

Tags: c++

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline

In this page, the std::getline defined as followed,

```
template< class CharT, class Traits, class Allocator >
std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& getline( std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>& input,
                                           std::basic_string<CharT,Traits,Allocator>& str,
                                           CharT delim );
```

so I thought, "getline" needs to take the template parameters, but the following example doesn't need to take it.

```
std::getline(std::cin, name);
```

could someone explain to me why?

Why do I not have to call it like this:

```
std::getline<SomeType, SomeOtherType>(std::cin, name);
```

Comment: How would you expect it to be called? `std::getline<SomeType, SomeOtherType>(std::cin, name)` or something else? The answer depends on what you thought there should be.

Comment: have a look at Template argument deduction https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: yeah, I thought it should be called as `std::getline<SomeType, SomeOtherType>(std::cin, name)` something like that

Comment: your question is not specific to `getline`, but rather general for templates. I didnt find a good duplicate. This is kind of related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42125179/c-template-argument-type-deduction, though it presumes that you already know a bit of what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction :

**Template argument deduction**

> In order to instantiate a function template, every template argument
> must be known, but not every template argument has to be specified.
> When possible, the compiler will deduce the missing template arguments
> from the function arguments.

This means that under certain circumstances the compiler is able to figure out the type on it's own and you don't need to manually specify it. In your case when you call `std::getline(std::cin, name);` both `std::cin` and `name` have a type known at compile time, so the compiler is able to do the work for you.

Comment: @ben1840 What does "_15char_" mean? I noticed that you said that to freakish below too.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo the comment requires 15 characters, so i just filled it with something

Comment: @ben1840 something like `"thank you very much!"` or `"thank you! I appreciate it"` is more than 15 chars, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

C++ compilers are smart and can deduce these template arguments based on passed parameters. Like in this case:

```cpp
template<class T>
void print(T arg) {
    std::cout << arg;
};
```

which you can use like this:

```cpp
print(1);  // int
print("foo");  // const char*
print(true);  // bool
```

You can read more about it here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The standard is no longer free unfortunately. But it is part of the standard.