# Understanding template type deduction Case 1 in Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

In his book **Effective Modern C++**, section **Item 1: Understand template type deduction**, Scott Meyers has said the following while discussing **Case 1: ParamType is a Reference or Pointer, but not a Universal Reference**

> These examples all show lvalue reference parameters, but type deduction works
> exactly the same way for rvalue reference parameters. Of course, only rvalue
> arguments may be passed to rvalue reference parameters, but that restriction
> has nothing to do with type deduction.

The lvalue reference examples given in the section before the quoted paragraph are as follows.

If this is our template,

```
template<typename T>
void f(T& param); // param is a reference
```

and we have these variable declarations,

```
int x = 27;          // x is an int
const int cx = x;    // cx is a const int
const int& rx = x;   // rx is a reference to x as a const int
```

the deduced types for param and T in various calls are as follows:

```
f(x);  // T is int, param's type is int&
f(cx); // T is const int, param's type is const int&
f(rx); // T is const int, param's type is const int&
```

---

**The Question:** For me, the paragraph quoted above, is a bit confusing for the following reason.

If I try to workout myself, the Case 1 example that deals with rvalue references, how should it look? May be like the following?

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param); // param is an rvalue reference
```

But isn't this case the same as Case 2: ParamType is a Universal Reference?

How can an rvalue reference be shown in Case 1 without it automatically becoming a Universal/Forwarding reference, since this is in a type deduced context?

One way to understand this is may be to map it to Case 2 sub case 2, where the initializing expression is an rvalue. In that case it is specified to work just as Case 1. So may be this is a loop back from Case 2 to Case 1.

Comment: Perhaps the confusion is that `T&&` is a universal reference when `T` is a template, but an rvalue reference when it is not (like `void f(int&&);`). It is unfortunate that `&&` happens to be used for both cases.

Comment: @BoP - Agree. Even Scott Meyers says the same in a comment on his blog [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) - "the committee recognized the distinction between rvalue and universal references, and they considered using different syntax for them. Ultimately, they rejected this idea, which I personally think is unfortunate"

Comment: I was extremely confused by this paragraph in the book as well, and I google searched the exact quote with quotation marks to find this paragraph. Pretty sure it's a mistake by Meyers, since there's no such thing as "r-value reference template parameters"

Comment: xdavidliu - Even I feel it's a mistake in the book. But sadly this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47125430/2130670 on SFO copies that Item form the book including the essence of the quoted paragraph. And it's a pretty well upvoted answer. :-(

Comment: so if you read "Case 2: ParamType is a Universal Reference"  one more time, you'll notice that he mentioned in the second bullet point :
If 'expr' is an rvalue, the “normal” (i.e., Case 1) rules apply. 
f(27); // 27 is rvalue, so T is int, // param's type is therefore int&& . it really depends on the contexts in which you call template functions.

Comment: @Sami - So what you mean is that it is actually to be understood as a loop back from Case 2 to Case 1, as I surmise in the last para of the question. Right?

Comment: @DhwaniKatagade True. If you check item24, you'll notice that (it is about a universal reference). For instance when we have the following, it will be deduced as int&&  
template <typename T>
void s(T&& param)
{

}
int main()
{
 s(10);}

Comment: @Sami - I understand what you say. Item 24 in the book pretty much states that T&& in a type deducing context is a Universal Reference. When initialized by an rvalue, it converges to an rvalue reference, due to reference collapsing rules (Item 28 in the book). In that sense the paragraph quoted in the question just should not have been there under Case 1, because Case 1 is defined by the predicate [ParamType is a Reference or Pointer, but not a Universal Reference], and Case 2 specifically covers Universal References.

Comment: @DhwaniKatagade I agree. That quoted part in your question made me confused for some time too while reading the book. also he mentioned "In particu
lar, when universal references are in use, type deduction distinguishes between lvalue
arguments and rvalue arguments. That never happens for non-universal references."  here i found that ok , this universal reference only cares about value category of an expr unlike Case1. 

About the confusion. you can email him and let him know. He is open to suggestions.

Comment: Technically Forwarding and Universal are different concepts. What was offered as Universal Reference never was recognized by cimmitee. That edition of text is quite dated (and was outdated by final C++11 release). Some re-prints\ttanslations are sloppy, because that was removed by errata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paragraph quoted in the question should not have been there in the book.

This is clarified in the errata page for Effective Modern C++ maintained by the author Scott Meyers [here](https://www.aristeia.com/BookErrata/emc++-errata.html). To quote from the source.

> The third paragraph (beginning with "These examples all show lvalue
> reference  parameters, but type deduction works exactly the same way
> for rvalue reference parameters") should be removed. When the type of
> param in the template f on page 11 is changed to an rvalue reference
> (i.e., to have type "T&&"), it becomes a universal reference, and then
> the rules for Case 2 (on pages 13-14) apply.

Taking the suggestion from @Sami I mailed Scott, and the gentleman pointed me to the errata.

In hind sight I realize, even a search for "Effective Modern C++ Errata" should have resolved the question.

Answer (score 0):

Not really. You can have function that accepts rvalue reference that would follow the same type deduction rule as described by Scott, just that it won't really be created in the similar fashion Case I is described unless we tweak it. Consider the following code.

```
template<typename T>
class Foo {
public:
    void bar(T&& param) {
    //...
    }
};

...
int value = 20;
Foo<int> ob;
ob.bar(val);                 // error - passing lvalue
ob.bar(20);                // valid - passing rvalue
ob.bar(std::move(value));  // valid
```

Now here, bar is the function you are looking for, i.e. it wouldn't accept lvalues. Note that it is not the case of universal referencing since we aren't templatizing the function but the class. While creating the object of the class Foo, we state the type to be int i.e. now T is int, hence reference collapsing won't apply to it. One good example would be push_back function defined in [std::vector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html).

Comment: Satyam - The object creation of class Foo is specifying the template parameter as int. So in this case type deduction is not coming into play. The cases that Scott mentions are for type deduction scenarios. I feel that the paragraph quoted in the question just should not have been there in the book.